# How to write uncertainties with the \pm symbol "10 ± 1 K" by using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, parsing

Using the `siunitx` package, if I specify an error with the `\pm` symbol then it automatically converts it to a form using parenthesis. I would like it to not do this and keep the `\pm` symbol, but still space the elements of the quantity and symbol in a good way.

e.g. `\SI{10 \pm 2}{\kelvin} would produce 10(1) K`

I would like it to produce: `10\pm1 K` or something similar with spacing taken care of.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want the `separate-uncertainty` switch, p.30 of the documentation.

```
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
```

sets this format for every number, or

```
\SI[separate-uncertainty=true]{whatever}
```

just for one.

Comment: Ant, you're a star, just the correct option. I'm surprised I didn't find it myself as I thought I did a search for "uncertainty" in the manual. No matter. Thanks very much

Comment: I'd note that `\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}` is also an option, which can be called in your document before you need the format change.

Comment: In version v3 of ```siunitx```, use ```\qty``` instead of ```\SI```.

Answer (score 27):

I've just come across the same problem and this is how I solved it to my satisfaction:

in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true,multi-part-units=single]{siunitx}
```

in the text:

```
(\SI{284(10)}{\ampere})
```

Produces the following output:
284 ± 10 A

If multi-part-units=single option isn't given, the result will look like:
((284 ± 10) A)
which, in my opinion, is less than optimal.

HTH

Comment: Hmm, it even seemed `multi-part-units=single` was sufficient for me. You don't need the first part to achieve the same result... but that's 5 years later.

Comment: I needed the first part as of 06/2019.

Comment: I had to use both `separate-uncertainty=true` to create the pm sign and `multi-part-units=single` to get rid of the parenthesis (i want 850±15 nm instead of (850±15) nm )