# Remove parentheses from number with uncertainty and the separate-uncertainty=true option with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27703/in-the-siunitx-package-how-do-i-get-it-to-produce-uncertainties-with-the-pm-sym).
Using the `separate-uncertainty=true` option with **siunitx**, a number like `\SI{100 \pm 12}{\kelvin}` would be output as (100 \pm 12) K

I want to get rid of the parentheses. Now there is a `bracket-numbers = false` option, which doesn't seem to work in this instance. I can do `open-bracket={}, close-bracket={}` in the options and this will work, but it seems rather brute force, as I intend to apply this to the whole document.

Does any one know a better way to sort this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get rid of the parentheses while keeping the expression mathematically correct, the unit must be supplied to both the base number and the uncertainty. You can achieve this by setting `separate-uncertainty,multi-part-units = repeat`, which for

```
\SI{100 \pm 12}{\kelvin}
```

will output

[image]

If you really only want the unit once, without parentheses around the base number and uncertainty, you can set `multi-part-units=single`:

[image]

Comment: Super, thanks Jake. I wish I could read a manual :>

Comment: I've noticed that this with `separate-uncertainty=true, multi-part-units=single` solution doesn't work lists, e.g., `\SIlist{21.0\pm2.8;19.7\pm3.5}{\celsius}` still results in (21.0±2.8) and (19.7±3.5) °C in stead of the desired 21.0±2.8 and 19.7±3.5 °C. Any ideas? :)